# Filtering df using .loc and unexpected result returned

Tags: python, pandas

I merged 2 dfs together to compare data side by side and now I want to sort the new df by a condition. I did a .loc filter (see below) but for some reason Im getting a match and Im not sure how. It could be related to the None values in the column. Also when I try and filter for None or "None" I receive a blank df.

All the columns are object types, I checked the ID columns for blank spaces and I don't see any.

here's my filter

```
df = merged_df.loc[(merged_df['Areacode_1'] != merged_df['Areacode_2']) & (merged_df['loc_1'] != merged_df['loc_2']) ]
```

Check out this df. **Im not sure why I'm getting this result back**:

```
Name     loc_1    Areacode_1     loc_2     Areacode_2

Jerry    NAN        None         None        None
```

Comment: in [this section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing) of the doc about missing values, there is a warning section explaining that Pandas considers `None` having the same behavior for equality than np.nan, aka `None == None` return `False` (in pandas) while in Python, this equality return `True`. I believe if you want to filter the None first, you can use `isna` like `df.loc[df['Areacode_1'].isna()]` (or `notna` if you want to remove them)

Comment: I updated the columns that im looking at and the comparison. One column shows NAN and another None. Do you think its related to the same thing?

Comment: Yes, `np.nan != None` return True (in python too) and `None != None` return True in Pandas. with your example I'm unsure as if your NAN is not a string though, but if it is a proper missing value np.nan, then it is normal that this row is returned

Answer (score 0):

It reminds me a lot about the 3-value logic of the database world. It does throw you off sometimes. The simpler way is to use the `ne` (not equal) function which handles `None` the way you would expect:

```py
cond = (
    merged_df['Areacode_1'].ne(merged_df['Areacode_2'])
    & merged_df['loc_1'].ne(merged_df['loc_2'])
)
df = merged_df.loc[cond]
```